# AWS Federated User Name for Terraform aws_iam_user_policy_attachment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I would like to get the **name** of my Federated User on AWS in order to be able to attach a policy on [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_user_policy_attachment):

```
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  user       = aws_iam_user.user.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
}
```

Right now, I found the ARN by building it like `"arn:aws:sts::<account_id>:federated-user/<role_name>/<user_id>"`

Also, by using `aws cli` with command `aws sts get-caller-identity`, if got some format like `"arn:aws:sts::<account_id>:assumed-role/<role_name>/<user_id>"`

Do you know any way to get the name without having to create an AWS CloudTrail as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74958206/how-to-find-the-arn-of-sso-federated-user-in-aws)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And where do you want to use that federated user ARN?

Comment: I want to attach a policy in Terraform to that Federated User, just this is only possible by name and until now, I've only got the ARN.

Comment: You need to attach your policy to the Role instead.

Comment: Cannot restrict more the policy? It should be possible if I can get the name of the user.

Comment: You can only attach permissions policies to IAM Users and Roles.  Your federated sessions work by assuming a Role; the session principal gets the permissions defined in the policies attached to the Role.  The only sort of policy that can be attached to a session principal is a "session policy", which does not grant permissions.